# Where should I set 'Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"' Header in my apache2 server?

Tags: server, cors, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, access-control

I want to access other servers from my server.
When I try to sent a GET/POST request to www.posttestserver.com, it is established successfully. 

In response, that server provides me response header as:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
>
> Connection:Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Encoding:gzip
>
> Content-Length:129
>
> Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Date:Tue, 13 Jun 2017 07:24:27 GMT
>
> Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
>
> Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
>
> Vary:Accept-Encoding

Then, how do I set this same type of header:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

over my server, so that other websites accessing my server receive this in their response headers?

My server is apache2 hosted on ubuntu 16.04.

Note:
I have set this header:

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf in  section, 

and in .htaccess file in /var/www/html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on ubuntu, it would be preferable to create a short config file in /etc/apache2/conf-available/ and then use a2enconf to enable it.

This allows you to keep the shipped configuration files unmodified.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Will try this and let you know. :)